# Perl File::Find::Rule to exclude a single dir

Tags: perl, file, file-search

I have the below shown directory structure.

1. I would like to get just the project names in my @project. `@project=('project1','project2')`;
2. I would like to exclude `OLD` directory and its sub directories in `@project`
3. I would like to get latest file in the subdirectories for all projects in `@project`. i.e., for `project1`, latest file is in sub directory `2014`, which is `foobar__2014_0916_248.txt`

How can I frame a rule to achieve this?

```
use strict;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Data::Dump;
my $output       = "/abc/def/ghi";
my @exclude_dirs = qw(OLD);
my @projects     = File::Find::Rule->directory->in("$output");
dd \@projects;
```

My Dir Structure:

```
.
├── project1
│   ├── 2013
|        ├── file1_project1.txt
│   └── 2014
|         ├── foobar__2014_0912_255.txt
|         ├── foobar__2014_0916_248.txt
├── project2
│   ├── 2013
|        ├── file1_project2.txt
│   └── 2014
|         ├── foobarbaz__2014_0912_255.txt
|         ├── foobarbaz__2014_0916_248.txt
└── OLD
    └── foo.txt
```

Comment: Do in two steps 1) Find the projects, and 2) For each project, find the latest file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ikegami suggested, just do this in two steps.

1. First find your project names
2. Second find the latest file

The following does this using [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) and [`Path::Class::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::Rule)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;

my $testdir = dir('testing');

for my $project ( $testdir->children ) {
    next if !$project->is_dir() || $project->basename eq 'OLD';

    my $newest;

    my $next = Path::Class::Rule->new->file->iter($project);
    while ( my $file = $next->() ) {
        $newest = $file if !$newest || $file->stat->mtime > $newest->stat->mtime;
    }

    print "$project - $newest\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
testing/project1 - testing/project1/2014/foobar__2014_0916_248.txt
testing/project2 - testing/project2/2014/foobarbaz__2014_0916_248.txt
```

Comment: I couldnt install Path::Class::Rule in my system . Tried from `cpan> install Path::Class::Rule` . It gave an error `Warning: Cannot install Path::Class::Rule;, don't know what it is.` . Tried `curl -k -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo Path::Class` which throwed an error too

Comment: It's not required to use `Path::Class`, I simply like that branch of modules since it easily enables cross platform file system handling.   You could easily iterate over your base directory using a different method and search a project tree using `File::Find::Rule`.  It just might take more code.

Comment: If you want to explore why you can't install those modules, perhaps start a new question as the error message your getting doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did it...posted another question..Thanks

Comment: @sravs448 Your new question has nothing to do with your error installing `Path::Class::Rule`. Oh well.

Comment: @sravs448 I just noticed, it looks like you ran `install Path::Class::Rule;` (with a semi-colon) from the CPAN shell. Drop the semi-colon, or simply run `cpan install Path::Class::Rule` from the command line.

Comment: surely will try that. Here is the link for my new question. Let  me know incase you know the solution. Thanks . `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900989/perl-filefindrule-to-find-latest-file-in-directories`